# Как может быть модератор с единицей репутации?

Tags: поддержка, дух-сообщества

[Это ссылка на модератора с 1 реп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0). Объясните как так произошло, если модераторов выбирают и для участия нужно, по-моему, 350 реп?

Comment: это специальная учетная запись.

Comment: [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/282647)

Comment: @Grundy можно подробнее? Это что работник форума который получает тут ЗП?

Comment: _It is an automated user agent, **not a real person**_

Comment: @Grundy это типо бот? (в английском не очень шарю) Если бот то что он делает?(желательно ответ на русском)

Comment: Да, это бот, что он делает, описано на его странице.

Comment: @Grundy, у нас разве перевода нет?

Comment: А я уж подумал снова какого-то ромба забанили ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я вот что-то не нашел на мете

Comment: Чисто теоретически можно стать модератором с 350 репутации и потом нахватать минусов.

Answer (score 2):

Данный модератор - бот, сделанный самими же админами. Он решает слишком рутинные задачи по типу сокрытия давнишних вопросов, закрытия плохих вопросов и делает прочую фигню.
В общем, всё норм, это не баг)